# not able to access node.js server from public ip of amazon windows instance

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, tcp

i am running a node.js server on my amazon micro instance of windows server. i am not able to access the node.js server using the public ip of amazon instance. I can access the node.js server from the instance using localhost:12345 but not able to access from other pc's using the public ip of the instance(54.200.211.174) 54.200.211.174:12345
here is my node.js code.....

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(12345);

console.log('Server running on port 12345.');
```

i also added the security rule for this port 
Type              Protocol  Port Range    Source
Custom TCP rule   TCP         12345        0.0.0.0/0

Please help me to access my node..js server using public ip of amazon instance

Comment: have you allowed port 12345 on the security group of the EC2 instance?

Answer (score 3):

**Solution:** ***Allow incoming traffic to your machine on required port***

Windows firewall blocking incoming traffic to your machine. you can follow below steps to add 'Inbound Rules':

1. Open 'Windows Firewall' (Search in Start menu)
2. Click on 'Advanced Setting' from left pane
3. Select 'Inbound Rules'
4. Click on 'New Rule...' from right pane
5. Select 'Port' and Click 'Next'
6. Select 'TCP' or 'UDP' you required and enter port no (*In your case port is 12345*)
7. Select 'Allow the connection' and click 'Next'
8. Select where you need to apply rule.
9. Provide name and description of rule and click on finish

Your issue will definitely get resolved!

Answer (score 0):

The windows firewall may be running and blocking incoming traffic. Test this be disabling the windows firewall.

Comment: Yes i realized this later and turn off my instance firewall and its working fine but i want to put exception in firewall so that i don't have to turn it off and still it works. How can i do that ? Any ideas...!!

Comment: You should post that as a separate question, but all you really need to do is add a rule to allow incoming port 12345, it should work.