# How to run nodejs on my public ip in windows?

Tags: node.js

I using windows 10 and want to run nodejs on port 3000 in my public address (just of me and for remote debugging).

So I open the port as say [by this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24502928/not-able-to-access-node-js-server-from-public-ip-of-amazon-windows-instance) and I run this code from [expressjs](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html)

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'))

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`))
```

Then I get [myip address](https://www.myip.com/), and tell my friend to open `http://256.266.266.266:3000/` in his chrome browser.

But the answer is `This site can’t be reached` `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`. why? how do I connect to my nodejs application in my public ip?

I do not have any antivirus or firewall as far as I know.

- Telnet `telnet 256.266.266.266 3000` say `.Could not open connection to the host, on port...`
- `netstat -an | find "3000"` say `TCP    0.0.0.0:3000    0.0.0.0:0      LISTENING`

Comment: Odds are that the address you think is your computer's public address … isn't. Most likely it is the IP address of your router and your computer doesn't have a public address of its own.

Comment: No, I change the ip in my question of course for security reasons. I don't want to reveal my true ip address..

Comment: the firewall on your windows machine is probably blocking all incoming connections to this port because it is considering it as unsafe